# Selecting certain elements from an array

Tags: php, arrays

I'm trying to remove everything from an array except DTSTART & DTEND

So I'm trying to convert this:

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [DTEND] => 20130417
        [DTSTART] => 20130403
        [UID] => cerog90g7-fcqls51z0wteew@airbnb.com
        [DESCRIPTION] => CHECKIN:  04/08/2012\nCHECKOUT: 04/17/2012\nNIGHTS:   14\nPHO
        [NE] =>     +1 504 914 0591\nEMAIL:    testhere@email.com\nPROPERTY: Breathtaking views over the lake\n
        [SUMMARY] => Name here (ED5ASC)
        [LOCATION] => Breathtaking views over the lake
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [DTEND] => 20131231
        [DTSTART] => 20131226
        [UID] => rtyrtyg90g7--t520wkwqv2i8@airbnb.com
        [DESCRIPTION] => CHECKIN:  12/26/2013\nCHECKOUT: 12/31/2013\nNIGHTS:   5\nPHON
        [E] =>     +44 7843 387767\nEMAIL:    floraking@hotmail.com\nPROPERTY: Breathtaking views over the lake\n
        [SUMMARY] => Name here (JrtyKW9)
        [LOCATION] => Breathtaking views over the lake
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [DTEND] => 20121123
        [DTSTART] => 20121117
        [UID] => ntry5rxts23--qe9rtyrywi0@airbnb.com
        [SUMMARY] => Not available
    )
```

)

to look like this:

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [DTEND] => 20130417
        [DTSTART] => 20130403
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [DTEND] => 20131231
        [DTSTART] => 20131226
    )
)

[2] => Array
    (
        [DTEND] => 20121123
        [DTSTART] => 20121117
    )
)
```

I've searched for loads of options but I need to be able to just select these two elements and discard the rest, I will be using it with different arrays that have different values so can't just specify the elements to remove as they will vary.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$newArray = array();
foreach ($array as $k => $v) {
  $newArray[$k]['DTEND'] = $v['DTEND'];
  $newArray[$k]['DTSTART'] = $v['DTSTART'];
}
```

**edit:** an alternative, since you mentioned trying to do it with one of the array iterator functions..

```
array_walk($array, function(&$v){
  $v = array('DTEND' => $v['DTEND'],'DTSTART' => $v['DTSTART']); 
});
```

**edit2:** because I have no life...yet another alternative...

```
array_walk($array, function(&$v){
  $v = array_intersect_key($v, array_flip(preg_grep('~^DT(END|START)$~', array_keys($v))));
});
```

I don't know which one is fastest/most efficient but my money is probably on the 2nd one.

Comment: Awesome thanks, I was trying things like array-filter and array-search but your answer is just so simple :)

Answer (score 1):

you can delete key/value hashes from each element

```
unset($array[0]['UID']);
unset($array[0]['DESCRIPTION');
//...
unset($array[999]['UID']);
unset($array[999]['DESCRIPTION');
```

in this case it's faster to make a new array, like crayon violent suggested.